# wordpress custom fields loop

Tags: customization, loop

I need to do wordpress custom fields loop: here is the code to describe better:

```
<?php 
$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'recipe',
    'meta_key' => 'recipe_star_rating',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order' => 'DESC',
   // 'taxonomy' => 'difficulty',
));



 global $wp_query;
       
      $total_results = $wp_query->found_posts;

      echo '<h2>"'.$term->name . '" Recipes</h2>';
      
      echo '<h4 class="tcount">'. $total_results . ' results</h4>';    ?>
      
     <hr class="aloha" />
           
    <?php order_properties_menu(); ?>
       
     <hr class="aloha" />
        
        
   <?php $counter = 0; ?>
   
<?php while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post();  ?>


    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                    <?php echo Chefscuisine_Template_Loader::load( 'recipes/grid' ); ?>
        </div>
        
     
            
        <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
        
          <? if ($counter % 4 === 0) { 
                echo '<div class="midad">Advert 336x280px Here!</div>';
            } ?>
```

I got listing but I need now by tahonomy eg. average-difficulty from taxonomy template, how to make it just by average difficulty or easy to cook thta are custom fields. Its pulling from category template called taxonomy-difficulties.php

Answer (score 0):

I can just guess that there are numeric values inside `recipe_star_rating` post meta.
Try this one if you have a numeric value, or just `meta_value` if there are string values.

```
$args = array(
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_key' => 'recipe_star_rating',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num' 
); 

$query = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) :
    $counter = 0;
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) :  $query->the_post(); 
        $counter++;
        the_title(); 
        echo "<br>"; 
    endwhile; 
    wp_reset_postdata();
endif;
```

Comment: this is not working in my loop empty

Comment: Do you recieve any errors?

Comment: I edit an answer. Noticed that you have `the_post()` inside your while loop, it should be `$query->the_post()`. Also you should reset postdata after custom WP_Query loop. Try this code, if it works, you can later modify it for your purpose (it works for "post" post type)

Comment: anything does not work with this I got empty loop $args = array(
    'orderby' => 'recipe_star_rating' ,
    'order' => 'DESC',
);

Comment: nothing works I have empty loop

Comment: Here is some sucess now I need to display every 4th ad with the code